# ORDER BY COUNT is slow

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

A table (**phototag**) consists of two foreign key columns (**photoid**, **tagid**). I want to get the most related photos based on their tags.

There are 4 million photos with 5-10 tags. For example, the photoid **10009** has 6 tags. I need photos that have similar tags.

```
SELECT photoid
FROM phototag
WHERE photoid != 10009
  AND tagid IN (21192, 3501, 35286, 21269, 16369, 48136)
GROUP BY photoid
ORDER BY COUNT(photoid) DESC
LIMIT 24;
```

Without `ORDER BY COUNT` the query is super fast.

I tried but no result:

- Optimizing table
- making a primary key based on two columns
- indexing columns separately
- switching InnoDB to MyISAM

UPDATE

Here is the result with `explain` prefix

[image]

Comment: Is the _only_ large query which you need to run?

Comment: yes. But if you advise me to try a different structure, I can try

Comment: You may maintain a summary count table, where every time you insert a new record into `phototag`, you also increment a counter in the summary table.

Comment: @Ulugbek Could you please prefix the query with `explain` to get us the execution plan. I think Tim's index suggestion is performance-tuned and should solve the issue. And if you are using 8.0, try `explain analyze` to get us the execution time as well

Comment: @blabla_bingo Updated question with Explain prefix as you suggested.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Could you please explain more about summary count table?

Comment: The `ORDER BY COUNT(photoid) DESC` part unfortunately couldn't not be covered by the index and results in a filesort job for MySQL. Could you also run `explain analyze` and give us the time spent on filesort? (Should be the topmost line from the output) . NOTE it does not work on version 5.x or below.

Comment: `explain analyze` is not working for me, but I can tell you that query without sorting is very fast and time with sorting is around 5 minutes

Comment: Is it correct to say that you also need this to work with other photoid values, and that the list of tags will come from that photo? (That is, you want the 24 photos with the highest number of tags in common with another arbitrary?)

Comment: @MatBailie You are right.

Comment: Then the summary table idea doesn't work. You're forced to check each and every photo every time (removing the order by means the database only has to count the results for 24 photos, but your need to order the results forces all 4 million photos to be checked). Your choices are; live with it, get a bigger CPU and more RAM, or think of a simpler version of "similar" (such as; pick the "rarest" tag from your photo and find all other photos that also have that One tag).

Comment: @MatBailie Is it possible to speed up with subquery or self inner join?

Comment: @Ulugbek Neither will help. Your problem isn't the way you word the query, your problem is that your query, with and order by, needs to check ***every*** photo ***every*** time. Until you remove that behaviour (by changing how you define "similar") indexes, sub-queries, etc, are going to make very little difference, as you're still scanning the entire table...

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.  The indexes for the link table are probably inadequate.

Comment: Checking many millions of rows will not be fast.  The goal is to avoid having to do such.

Comment: @RickJames - It's a table of two columns, and the op has tried indexes with `(a,b)` ***and*** `(b,a)`.   The problem is ***sorting*** 4 million results *(of `COUNT(*)`)* to find the top 24.

Answer (score 0):

Count queries are notoriously difficult to optimize.  However, we should be able to index the `WHERE` clause.  Consider trying the following compound index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON phototag (photoid, tagid);
```

This index covers the `WHERE` clause, as well as the `SELECT`, and should be usable while aggregating with `GROUP BY`.

Another totally different approach would be to create a summary table.  This table would take the following structure:

```
photoid | count
10000   | 25
10001   | 300
...     | ...
```

Every time you insert a new record into `phototag` which is *not* one of the blacklisted `tagid` values, you would also update the summary table.  For example, assuming you had just inserted a whitelisted tag for `photoid` 10001, you would execute the following update:

```sql
UPDATE summary
SET count = count + 1
WHERE photoid = 10000;
```

Now, with this summary table in hand, your original query just becomes:

```sql
SELECT photoid
FROM summary
WHERE photoid != 10009
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 24;
```

Note that there is no aggregation needed.  Instead, the aggregation is happening all along the way in the summary table.

Comment: I run your query and tried again. No result. It did not help because I have already primary key based on both columns which have already indexed

Comment: It is going to take some time to run this query against a table with 50 million records.

Comment: Would it be faster with subquery or inner join?

Comment: I think the summary table isnt going to help. There isn't a white-list of tags, as the op states; `For example, the photoid 10009 has 6 tags. I need photos that have similar tags.` *(So, the relevant tags will vary as the photo being compared against varies.)*

Comment: @MatBailie You are right.

Comment: Shouldn't this use `tagid` instead of `photoid`??

Answer (score 0):

Without ORDER BY clause, if the database finds 24 records that satisfy the condition, it may return the results before reading all table records.
With the ORDER BY clause, the database must read all records in order to sort them according to the count result.

The IN operator makes queries difficult to optimize. Database needs to repeatedly access the index as many times as the number of variables. Plan generators are easy to induce to do table scans in these situations.

I don't think creating index is helpful. However, `phototag(tagid, photoid)` is better than `phototag(photoid, tagid)` because the database cannot use the index when the condition is negative.

Comment: indexing phototag(tagid, photoid) did not help

Comment: @Ulugbek - If you kept `INDEX(tagid)`, that may have gotten in the way.  Drop `INDEX(a)` when you add `INDEX(a,b)`

Answer (score 0):

If you change what you mean by "similar", you can reduce the amount of work the database engine needs to do. (Mostly, avoiding sorting the "score" for all or most of you 4 million photos.

For example, you could pick ***all*** photos that share your target photo's ***one*** "rarest" tag.

```
SELECT *
  FROM phototag
 WHERE photoid != 10009
   AND tagid = (
         SELECT tagid
           FROM phototag
          WHERE tagid IN (
                  SELECT tagid
                    FROM phototag
                   WHERE photoid = 10009
                )
       GROUP BY tagid
       ORDER BY COUNT(*), tagid
          LIMIT 1
       )
```

With indexes on both `(tagid, photoid)` and `(photoid, tagid)`.

This massively reduces the number of rows that need to be processed and makes that processing easier.

***But...***

It is ***not*** what you originally asked for, ***and*** it's possible that it will return zero matching photos.

***What it is...***

An example of a different definition of "similar" that can reduce the amount of data being processed, leading to faster queries.

***So, there's your trade off...***

Either:

- you accept the slow performance of a query that reads and re-sorts pretty much the whole table
- you redefine "similar" to something "easier to solve" but probably "less good"

Comment: Probably I prefer the slow performance because just matching one tagid does not mean that these photos are simular. But anyway thank you for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

A summary table would be best (cf [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) ).  But, without such:

```
SELECT photoid
    FROM phototag
    WHERE photoid != 10009
      AND tag IN ('this', 'that, ...)
    GROUP BY photoid
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 24;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE phototag (
    photoid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    tag VARCHAR(99),
    PRIMARY KEY(photoid, tag),
    INDEX(tag, photoid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Notes:  Do not include a id; do use composite indexing.

I find that having the tag as a string, not an id simplifies the coding and possibly speeds up execution -- rather than first having to find the tagids.  Think of it this way:   An `INT` is 4 bytes, but what is the `AVG(LENGTH(tag))`?  Possibly not much more than 4.

Consider `FULLTEXT`:

If, in the photo table (or a parallel table), you hade a `tags TEXT` column and `FULLTEXT(tags)`, then this might work *much* faster:

```
SELECT photoid
    FROM photos
    WHERE    MATCH(tags) AGAINST("this that ...")
    ORDER BY MATCH(tags) AGAINST("this that ...") DESC
    HAVING photoid != 10009
    LIMIT 24;
```

(Be cautious of min token length and stopwords.)

(It may sort better with `IN BOOLEAN MODE` and/or `NATURAL LANGUAGE`.)

Comment: I'm not convinced `match` or any other "speed up the scoring" technique will help.  The primary burden is that `ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 24` *(where the score is the number of tags two photos have in common)* involves scoring ***all*** 4 million photos and then ***sorting*** those 4 million results, to get the top 24.  *(Note: the summary table doesn't work, because it needs to work for any given photo; to find the top 24 photos that have the most tags in common with another given photo.)*

Comment: @MatBailie - MATCH 'should' quickly eliminate the ones that don't count -- probably much faster than a full table scan.l